# Set up nftables to only allow connections through a vpn and block all ipv6 traffic

Tags: firewall, vpn, nftables

I am trying to set up a nftables firewall on my archlinux distribution that only allows traffic through a vpn (and blocks all ipv6 traffic in order to prevent any ipv6 leaks)

I have been playing around with it for a while now and ended up with a configuration that lets me browse the web, even though as far as I understand nftable so far, it should not let me do that. The ruleset is pretty short and looks like this:

```
table inet filter {
    chain input {
            type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
            jump base_checks
            ip saddr VPN_IP_ADRESS udp sport openvpn accept
    }

    chain forward {
            type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
    }

    chain output {
            type filter hook output priority 0; policy drop;
            ip daddr VPN_IP_ADRESS udp dport openvpn accept
            oifname "tun0" accept
    }

    chain base_checks {
            ct state { related, established} accept
            ct state invalid drop
    }
}
```

I tried to find my way thorugh with trial and error and had many other rules in there, but with just this, i am able to connect to the VPN server first and then browse the web. Once I remove the last rule from the outout chain though, it won't let me browse the web anymore.

I am completely new to this and pretty much overall clueless, trying to learn. Unfortunately, the documentation on nftables is not that extensive, so I am kind of stuck at the moment.

From what I understand so far, this setup should allow to make a connection to the vpn but it should not allow any other incoming traffic - yet I can browse the web without problems.

Does anyone know why it works and how i should proceed with the setup of nftables to get a more complete setup?

Answer (score 0):

You allow incoming traffic with `state` `related` and `established`. HTTP traffic is initiated by your client sending a request, responses will be matched by `established` rule in output chain. Assuming your routing goes via VPN, initial traffic out is accepted by your `oif "tun0" accept` rule.

Comment: thanks, so how do i specify the type of package that i check the state for?
by that i mean how do i put those commands that you told me in there?

Comment: Rules mentioned already exist in your tables your provided in question, (hence you can browse web). You can jump to another chain if you wish to do further filtering to `related`/`established` traffic.